# In visual studio code, how to find out which thread has a certain file open when debugging Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to solve a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283925/conda-build-access-error-on-just-created-directory) that results from the program trying to move a directory it already has open elsewhere. The program is written in Python and I managed to run it in the Visual Studio Code debugger. Now I'm on a breakpoint directly before the line where it will fail. In `procexp.exe` I can see that the process indeed has the directory in question open. However, it does not tell me more. Can I find out from the debugger where the directory was opened or at least in which thread? Or any other helpful information?

Edit: Possibly it was not the directory that was open, but some files underneath it. However, Windows consistently only reported the directory to be in use (in handle.exe, procexp.exe and rammap.exe).

Comment: Perhaps you can monkeypatch `builtins.open` to tell you when and where it opens the file.

Comment: @AlexHall But it's a directory. TBH I don't know how you would open a directory in Python (os.cwd() maybe?), but not with open().

Comment: I thought you'd misspoke. What does opening a directory *mean* in any language?